# Do I need Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5 nowadays?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade an angularJS project and I'm stucked on one question, but let me summerize the project:

We use AngularJS, gulp and node 8.
we currently cannot use the ES6 features, like arrow functions, const/let and so on.
I achieved that by installing babels plugin. But babel transpiles the code, and the company staff doesn't want that, cause it can make it difficult to debug on production(I know we can use sourcemaps, it will be suggested).
We just want to write ES6 code and read(on the browser) the same code as we do now (but with es5)

I upgraded node to 10 and I thought that by upgrading node, the app would accept the new ES6 features. But still crashes when using es6 syntax.

Can someone tell me why? If the browsers accepts, why gulp doesnt?

Comment: You "upgraded" to Node 10? You are aware, that this version is out of maintenance for about one and a half year by now? Current version is 18, current LTS is 16. Having said that: There is not enough information about your setup, your build-process ... to give any reasonable answer ... And "arrow functions" for instance are fully supported since node version 6

Comment: yeah, this is an old project. upgraded from v8 to v10 and maybe will upgrade more later.

Comment: What error message do you receive when your project "crashes" using es6 syntax?

Comment: You should make the case to the company to fund a rewrite/upgrade of the application to Node 20 LTS, and getting rid of all deprecated and vulnerable dependencies.  By using deprecated and unsupported software you are opening the door for unpatched and unidentified security vulnerability.  FYI: there are 144 known vulnerabilities for Nodejs (cvedetails.com), some are tagged with Node 10, but once Node 10 became deprecated they officially stopped marking them with node 10.